# If someone pleads guilty to a crime, can they be described as "convicted"?

Tags: word-usage, subjects, objects

If someone pleads guilty to a crime, can I then describe them as being "convicted"?  I recognise that a person who pleads guilty to a crime will have a **conviction** on their record.  The confusion arises because, in the passive phrase "John was convicted", the implication is that he was convicted **by** a subject.  It seems strange to say that John convicted himself.

To put it simply, is "John plead guilty" synonymous with "John was convicted"?

Comment: This is more legal than linguistic, but doesn’t a conviction involve a judgement? Someone can plead guilty and be found not guilty, in theory at least.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plea

Answer (score 4):

> To put it simply, is "John plead guilty" synonymous with "John was convicted"?

No. The court convicts John. John doesn't convict himself.

John would still be the *defendant* or the *accused*.

A person may plea guilty but not be convicted, for example if John was covering for Jane in order to protect her. John could then be convicted of a different crime (preventing the course of justice, interfering with the investigation etc) but not of the crime he plead guilty to.